# How to manage sharing on application resources base on CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I am familiar with legacy Web Application Development.
It seem make me confusing on developing app base on CouchDB.

*For example:*

There are two Nodejs apps, `App1` and `App2`.
I need one DBMS with two databases `app_1` and `app_2`; each have a separated table `users`; and each use difference connection info *(not use `root` user)*.
So, when doing authorization to manage resources all custom logic was coded on the JavaScript server-side.

*In contrast*

In CouchDB, there is one database named `_users`.

*I am wondering*

- Do I need to use that `_users` database for all apps ?
- Do I need to use same connection info for all apps ?
- How I manage the resource sharing for users in each app ? OR just do the same way *( custom logic base on JavaScript code server-side )*
- Exposing the CouchDB's HTTP API to public is a good idea ?

Would you please point me a good resources on this ?
*( I have go through the [Security Documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html) but still not get answer to my mind )*

Sincerely,
Liratanak

Answer (score 0):

I found [the correct answer](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization) ( but there no a perfect solution )

> CouchDB has not be designed to support per-document read-control

**Possible solutions**

- Database per user
- Smart proxy *( seem this the best for me among the four )*
- Document encryption on a per user basis
- Validate_doc_read function